# Unzip an entry to memory in Racket

Tags: racket, unzip

I'm trying to read a file entry. The program I have now:

```rkt
#lang racket
(require file/unzip)
(require xml)

(define (get-content file-name)
  (let ([in (open-input-file file-name #:mode 'binary)])
    (unzip-entry in
                 (read-zip-directory in)
                 #"content.xml")))
```

Currently the program writes a file `content.xml` into the filesystem. But I need to have it stored in memory (either as an output port, or as a string, or some return value) instead of polluting the filesystem. Could you tell me please how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, by passing in a custom `entry-reader` parameter to `unzip-entry`. Here's an example of how to do it:

```rkt
(define (unzip-entry->bytes path zipdir entry)
  (call-with-output-bytes
   (lambda (out)
     (unzip-entry path zipdir entry
                  (lambda (name dir? in)
                    (copy-port in out))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't used `file/unzip`, from reading the documentation it doesn't look like it's designed to support what you want.

All I can think of is the obvious work-around: Have `unzip-entry` write the file to the system temporary directory (use `(find-system-path 'temp-dir)` to get its location), open it, and read into memory.  Then either `delete-file` or let the system delete it as it normally does temp files.

---

Update:

Looks like I was tired when I read the docs last night, and misunderstood that using `make-filesystem-entry-reader` was required, rather than a convenience. Of course `unzip-entry` can take any function `(bytes? boolean? input-port? . -> . any)`. Instead see Chris' answer.